# Ubuntu 15.10 - jboss wildfly 9.0.2.Final, Eclipse Mars crash due to JVM error

Tags: java, eclipse, jdk

After I upgrade to Ubuntu 15.10 , when I start the jboss wildfly 9.0.2.Final and eclipse mars crashes due to JVM error. 
At that time I cannot access Chrome or Firefox browsers as well.

Most of the time I need to restart the Machine to fix it. However, that re-occur after some times.

If anyone can shed some light would be appreciated.

Error Is give below

*A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f06c67f0921, pid=6574, tid=139666575578880
 JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_66-b17) (build 1.8.0_66-b17)
 Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.66-b17 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
 Problematic frame:
 V  [libjvm.so+0x8e9921]  Node::rematerialize() const+0x1
 Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again*

Note Im using Oracle JDK 8

Comment: You can not assume that everyone knows wildfly.

Comment: Hope you know what is wildfly. However, do you have any idea ?

Comment: Which wildfly distro?

Comment: Jboss Wildfly 9.0.2.Final

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the exact same problem as you experienced.

Turns out a RAM memory module in my machine was broken. After removing the broken memory module everything went back to normal.